# WP and bootstrap: show 6 latest posts in two rows with <hr> separating them, and no <hr> when only 3 posts are on page

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap to build a wordpress blog and I have a code that generates a new bootstrap row after every 3rd post on the page. I figured out how to insert a hr tag in between the rows to separate them, but not to insert it after the last post on the page, since there are only 6 posts per page and the footer has a top border that looks the same as hr separator.

Here is the code:

```
  <div class="row">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 small-article" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="article">
      <p class="article-date"><?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?></p>
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
      <p class="article-short-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-learn-more">Read More</a>
    </article>
  <?php 
    $counter++;
    if ($counter == 6) {
      echo  '';
    }elseif($counter % 3 == 0){
      echo '</div><hr class="small-article-divider"><div class="row">'; 
    }
    endwhile; endif; 
  ?>
  </div><!-- /row -->
```

The part I can't figure out is how not to insert hr when there are only 3 posts on the page, or 1 row with 3 posts. Right now if there are 3 posts on the page it inserts hr which ruins the layout, since as I already mentioned, footer has a top border that looks the same as the hr separator.
Can anyone help me out with this?

edit:

As I mentioned to someone in the comments, Here is the logic behind what I need to accomplish: If there are more than 3 posts on the page, a new bootstrap row must be inserted after the 3rd post, with hr separating the rows. There must not be a separator, and no new row inserted after the 6th(last) post on the page, also no new row, and no separator when there are exactly 3 posts on the page.

Comment: 3 is divisible by 3, hence the `<hr />` being added.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ($counter == 3) : 
 //something
else if $counter == 6):
 //something
else($counter % 3 == 0):
 //something
endif;
```

Comment: Nope. There is no hr separator at all that way.

Comment: Perhaps i miss understood the question, check my update

Comment: It doesn't work. Here is the logic behind what I need: If there are more than 3 posts on the page, a new bootstrap row must be inserted after the 3rd post, with hr separating the rows. There must not be a separator, and no new row inserted after the 6th(last) post on the page, also no new row, and no separator when there are exactly 3 posts on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with a little help from a friend.

```
<?php 
$count = 0;

if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()): the_post();
        $count++;
    endwhile;
}
?>
<div class="row">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <article class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 small-article" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="article">
      <p class="article-date"><?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?></p>
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
      <p class="article-short-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-learn-more">Read More</a>
    </article>
  <?php 
    $counter++;
    if ($counter == 6) {
      echo  '';
    }elseif($counter % 3 == 0 && $count != 3){
      echo '</div><hr class="small-article-divider"><div class="row">'; 
    }
    endwhile; endif; 
  ?>
</div><!-- /row -->
```